# Group Footer to behave as Page Footer In SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I'm using SSRS 2008 to create a report. My report is table based, and features nested groups - The overarching group is a 'Cover Sheet' for the Details section of the report. The details section of the report can be variable in length, from under an inch in height to several pages long; this is dependent on the amount of data featured in a sub report placed in the details section (of which there might be one or multiple iterations).

The details section of the report is supposed to have a footer and the cover page is not, so essentially I'd like to have a group footer behave as a page footer. If the data presented in the group wasn't in a sub report, I could create an expression that generated white space in a text box to push the group footer down to the bottom of the page; I'm not sure how I'd do that with the variable length/iteration of the sub report. I've also tried to conditionally hide the page footer when the cover page (outer group) is visible but haven't found an appropriate means by which to do that.

I must be missing something here.

My questions are: 
How can I get my group footer to anchor at page bottom? 
or alternately, 
how can I conditionally hide the page footer for the cover sheet (outer group) but not the other pages?

Comment: Joeyjojo Shabadoo Please saw us how the report look like and what are the condition tou have try to hide the page footer?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following:

1. add page footer / header -> report menu add page header / footer
2. then click on the footer/ header on the design surface
3. in the properties menu -> General Part -> PrintOnFirstPage or PrintOnLastPage

Hope this helps(and I have your problem well understood)!

Regards,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2008 R2 or later, the visibility condition for header/footer items can be set based on PageName value.

For example, let's say outer group is based on column 'Year' and inner group is based on column 'Month'.
Set PageName for outer group as Fields!Year.Value and inner group as Fields!Month.Value

If the requirement is to hide footer cover sheet, check for PageName value to be between 1 to 12. Hide footer items if the condition fails.

PS: PageName is available under Properties for Tablix Member of the Row group.

Comment: is there a reference to the documentation you can cite?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/04/25/report-design-reset-page-number-on-group.aspx. This is good reference to understand the features added for group based page number and page name in SSRS 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

I've found that when you click on the whitespace of the page footer and check the properties, there's a property for **PrintOnFirstPage** and **PrintOnLastPage**. Changing **PrintOnFirstPage** to False will make it so the footer is not present on the report's first page.